# static methods and delay using the example of a traffic light (java/jframe)

Tags: java, methods, static, jframe, this

This should be an example of a traffic light.
My problem is that I don't know how to use a delay. (I've tried and searched but nothing helped)
And I can not use "this..." in the methods "green,yellow,red,yellowred" because they are static.
The button should toggle between "the automatic traffic light is on" and "It is off".
Please can somebody help me with this.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class AmpelAuto extends JFrame {
  // Anfang Attribute
  private JPanel jPanelOben = new JPanel(null, true);
  private JPanel jPanelMitte = new JPanel(null, true);
  private JPanel jPanelUnten = new JPanel(null, true);
  private JButton Toggle = new JButton();
  public boolean OnOff = true;
  // Ende Attribute
  //public int OnOff = 1;

  public AmpelAuto() {   
    // Frame-Initialisierung
    super();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    int frameWidth = 412; 
    int frameHeight = 543;
    setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (d.width - getSize().width) / 2;
    int y = (d.height - getSize().height) / 2;
    setLocation(x, y);
    setTitle("AmpelAuto");
    setResizable(false);
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(null);
    // Anfang Komponenten

jPanelMitte.setBounds(144, 160, 120, 120);
jPanelMitte.setOpaque(true);
jPanelMitte.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(0, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));
jPanelMitte.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
cp.add(jPanelMitte);
jPanelUnten.setBounds(144, 296, 120, 120);
jPanelUnten.setOpaque(true);
jPanelUnten.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(0, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));
jPanelUnten.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
cp.add(jPanelUnten);
jPanelOben.setBounds(144, 24, 120, 120);
jPanelOben.setOpaque(true);
jPanelOben.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(0, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));
jPanelOben.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
cp.add(jPanelOben);
Toggle.setBounds(160, 448, 80, 24);
Toggle.setText("Off");
Toggle.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
Toggle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
    Toggle_ActionPerformed(evt);
  }
});
Toggle.setBackground(Color.RED);
Toggle.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3, true));
cp.add(Toggle);

// Ende Komponenten
setVisible(true);
  } // end of main

  // Anfang Methoden
  public static void Green() {
    this.jPanelOben.setBackground(Color.WHITE);                   //green
    this.jPanelMitte.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
    this.jPanelUnten.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    System.out.println("Green");
  }

  public static void Yellow() {
    this.jPanelOben.setBackground(Color.WHITE);                   //yellow
    this.jPanelMitte.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); 
    this.jPanelUnten.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    System.out.println("Yellow");
  }

  public static void Red() {
    this.jPanelOben.setBackground(Color.RED);                   //red
    this.jPanelMitte.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
    this.jPanelUnten.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    System.out.println("Red");
  }

  public static void YellowRed() {
    this.jPanelOben.setBackground(Color.RED);                   //yellowRed
    this.jPanelMitte.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); 
    this.jPanelUnten.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    System.out.println("YellowRed");
  }

    
  public void Toggle_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO hier Quelltext einfügen
    if (OnOff) {
      OnOff = false;
      this.Toggle.setBackground(Color.green);
      this.Toggle.setText("On"); 
    } else if (!OnOff) {
        OnOff = true;
        this.Toggle.setBackground(Color.RED);
        this.Toggle.setText("Off");  
      } // end of if-else

  } // end of Toggle_ActionPerformed
    
  public static void Ampelphase(boolean OnOff) {
while (OnOff) { 
  Green();
  try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
  } catch(Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  } 
  if (OnOff) {
    Yellow();
    if (OnOff) {
      Red();
      if (OnOff) {
        YellowRed();
      } else {
        break;
      } // end of if-else
    } else {
      break;
    } // end of if-else
  } else {
    break;
  } // end of if-else
} // end of while
  }
    
    
    
  public static void wait(int ms)
  {
    try
    {
      Thread.sleep(ms);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ex)
    {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
  }
    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AmpelAuto();

  }
    
    
        // Ende Methoden
} // end of class AmpelAuto`
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is you don't know how to use Swing.  Swing is single threaded, so you can't use `Thread.sleep` in inject a delay.  Swing is also not thread safe, so you should not be updating the UI from outside the context of the event dispatching thread.  I would suggest that you take a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead

Comment: Thanks. That realy helps. Do you have an advice for my other problem too. The mixed up methods or rather the "this" that doesn't work and an't be let out because it is in a static  method but it has to be in a static otherwise it could not be called out.

Comment: 1) Your methods should NOT be static. 2) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character 3) Method names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: `static` and I have a love hate relationship - in your context, you can't use `this` as the `static` context does not have an associated object instance.  Instead, remove `static` and learn to live without it

Comment: Perfect, thanks y'all now it is working.
But  `Thread.sleep` works . I don't know why but it does